# Passing information between three classes, throwing exception. (Java)

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I made a topic the other day about a similar issue, I thought I'd solved it but then when I tried to take a users advice and split my code up into more OO compliant code I just keep running into the same exception.

Firstly I have my 'main' class which loads a JFrame and then loads an instance of the ComboBox class and an instance of the runButton class. Once it has displayed these it runs a while loop which waits for specific responses from the run button and will then load the appropriate web driver.

Here is the driver class.

```
public class DynamicBrowsers {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    BrowserBox b = new BrowserBox();
    GoButton g = new GoButton();
    JFrame IDE = new JFrame("IDE");
    IDE.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
    IDE.setContentPane(b);
    IDE.add(g);
    IDE.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
    IDE.pack();
    IDE.setVisible(true);

    WebDriver driver = null;    

    while (g.browserValue == 0){
        if(g.browserValue == 1){
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            System.out.println("FF!");
            break;
        }else if(g.browserValue == 2){
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            System.out.println("Chrome!");
            break;
        }else if(g.browserValue == 3){
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            System.out.println("IE!");
            break;
        }
    }
```

There's more in this class but it's unrelated and mostly just me testing what I can do in Selenium.

The classes it reads from are the BrowserBox class, which implements a combo box,  the code for that is :-

```
public class BrowserBox extends JPanel {

public String browserPick;
String[] browsers = {"Please Select a Browser","Mozilla", "Chrome", "IE"};
public JComboBox browserPicker = new JComboBox(browsers);     

public BrowserBox() { 

    add(browserPicker);

    ActionListener cbActionListener = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent listChoice) {

            String s = (String) browserPicker.getSelectedItem();//get the selected item

            switch (s) {//check for a match

                case "Please Select a Browser":
                    browserPick = "Please Select a Browser";
                    System.out.println(browserPick);
                    break;                
                case "Mozilla":                     
                    browserPick = "Mozilla";
                    System.out.println("Could have been a worse choice than " + browserPick);
                    break;
                case "Chrome":
                    browserPick = "Chrome";
                    System.out.println("Good choice picking " + browserPick);
                    break;
                case "IE":
                   browserPick = "IE";
                    System.out.println("For some reason you chose " + browserPick);
                    break;
                default:
                    browserPick = "Please Select a Browser";
                    System.out.println("No match selected, defaulting too " + browserPick);
                    break;
            } 
        }            
    };

    browserPicker.addActionListener(cbActionListener);

}
}
```

And finally the button, GoButton class :-

```
public class GoButton extends JButton {

public int browserValue = 0;
JButton runButton = new JButton("Run Test");
BrowserBox cb = new BrowserBox();

public GoButton() {

    add(runButton); 

    ActionListener bActionListener = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent runClicked) {

            if (cb.browserPick.equals("Mozilla")){
                browserValue = 1;     
                System.out.println("FF clicked " + browserValue);
            }
            else if (cb.browserPick.equals("Chrome")){
                browserValue = 2;
                System.out.println("Chrome clicked " + browserValue);
            }
            else if (cb.browserPick.equals("IE")){
                browserValue = 3;
                System.out.println("IE clicked " + browserValue);
            } 

        }

    };
    runButton.addActionListener(bActionListener);
}

}
```

This is where I'm getting the exception

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at GoButton$1.actionPerformed(GoButton.java:21)

I assume the problem is browserPick's value is not changing the way I'm expecting it too, which means the value is null and therefore not what I am looking for, but I can't work out why. Or how to fix it.

I'm sorry if my question is annoying, or if I'm doing something really stupid. Just trying to get a good ground in the surrounding Java before I dive into more Selenium.

Thank you,
Farrell

Comment: Have you heard of Safari? That's the best. Not Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

In your `GoButton` class you are creating a new instance of `BrowswerBox`

```
BrowserBox cb = new BrowserBox();
```

Which has no relationship to the instance that you added to your frame...

```
BrowserBox b = new BrowserBox();
GoButton g = new GoButton();
JFrame IDE = new JFrame("IDE");
IDE.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
IDE.setContentPane(b);
IDE.add(g);
IDE.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
IDE.pack();
IDE.setVisible(true);
```

Extending from `JButton` is literally overkill.  Not only that, but you create another instance of a `JButton` within it and add that to the button instead?

You could simply add an `ActionListener` directory to `g` (the instance of `GoButton`) which would have more capacity to reference the correct instance of `BrowserButton`

For example...

```
final BrowserBox b = new BrowserBox();
JButton g = new JButton("Run Test");
JFrame IDE = new JFrame("IDE");
IDE.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
IDE.setContentPane(b);
IDE.add(g);
IDE.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
IDE.pack();
IDE.setVisible(true);

g.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent runClicked) {
        WebDriver driver = null;
        if ("Mozilla".equals(b.browserPick)){
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            System.out.println("FF clicked " + browserValue);
        }
        else if ("Chrome".equals(b.browserPick)){
            System.out.println("Chrome clicked " + browserValue);
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        else if ("IE".equals(b.browserPick)){
            System.out.println("IE clicked " + browserValue);
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        } 
        if (driver != null) {
            // Drive away...
        }
    }
 });
```

My next point of concern is that fact that you are exposing `browserPicker` as `public`, which anybody could alter the available values, remove it, replace it and do generally nasty things.

Personally, I'd simple include the "Start Test" button as part of the `BrowswerBox` pane and make sure the components have `private` access.  If required, I'd supply a getter of some kind to return the value of the selected item instead...

I'd recommend that you spend some more time reading through [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and you might find [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) interesting as well.

**Updated**

I should also mention that this:

```
while (g.browserValue == 0){
    if(g.browserValue == 1){
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        System.out.println("FF!");
        break;
    }else if(g.browserValue == 2){
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        System.out.println("Chrome!");
        break;
    }else if(g.browserValue == 3){
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        System.out.println("IE!");
        break;
    }
}
```

Is not how you react to user interactions/changes in a GUI environment.  Most GUI's are event driven, that is, the user does something and you react to it.  I've updated the `ActionListener` in the previous example to be more "accurate"

Comment: Wow really helpful advice, and I will read those links tomorrow.  If I had enough rep to upvote you I would lol. I am getting big errors when trying to put the -

g.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {    line in though, figured it was just missing a ) but that failed too

Comment: It's probably got some "out of scope" variable references.  I've updated the example to be more accurate to how a GUI should work

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think tomorrow I'm going to do a bit more reading then maybe start from scratch using your approach here and getters / setters to communicate between the classes.  Sorry it was such a mess lol and thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't yet chosen a browser, then `browserPick` will be `null`. A variable being `null` when it shouldn't causes a `NullPointerException`. I assume you would probably want it to be "Please Select a Browser"...